# Difference of professor salaries between different department in the United States

Tags: united-states, reference-request, salary

Is there any research/study/survey/... that looked at the difference of professor salaries between different department in the United States?

Answer (score 7):

Here's [one](https://www.higheredjobs.com/salary/salaryDisplay.cfm?SurveyID=24) that's readily accessible, though the full data isn't public (but can be obtained).   Here's [another one](http://www.chronicle.com/article/Average-Faculty-Salaries-by/126586/) in a much more concise format, though a bit older.

At least for public universities, it's not too hard to do such a survey since our salaries are public record.  I haven't actually checked but I would imagine that the groups that have done these surveys keep them updated every so many years so you can use the ones I linked to to find more.

Comment: Note that sometimes the salaries you find online are not accurate.  My university's salaries were once posted by a 3rd party site in a very misleading manner to make the salaries seem higher than they are.

Comment: I'm skeptical the data in the second link is not misleading.  (Though +1--it's not your fault!)  It tells you something, but the variance among schools for a fixed department is so large (e.g., compare research vs teaching, and public vs private) that this should be controlled for to get a better sense of things.  E.g., the variance at my school among certain departments is much larger than what that aggregate data would indicate.